# UiScrollView: Bounce padding

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I want to manually set the padding for bouncing. How can i do this?
I have a horizontal scrollview containing e.g a 600px wide view but only 400px of this view should be really "scrollable" leaving 200px as aesthetic padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the contentSize 400px and put the 600px wide image inside it, positioned so that 100px sticks out either side (i.e. give it a negative origin position).

Views are not clipped to the bounds of their parent view in iOS unless the parent view has clipToBounds = YES.

Comment: worked, i just had to keep care of the default padding of 0.5 * scrollViewWidth